# MySQL search across three tables inner joined

Tags: mysql, whmcs

I have the following three tables in a MySQL database structured as so:

## tblinvoices

userid | id | taxrate | date

## tblinvoiceitems

userid | relid

## tblcustomfieldvalues

relid | value | fieldid

What I am trying to do is find all invoice numbers (tblinvoices.id) that are within a certain date range and have a taxrate of 0, and have a fieldid of 5 with a value containing letters.

This is how far I have got with the code to try and achieve this, unfortunately it's not working and I cannot see why. I know this is rather complex so any advice gratefully appreciated, I am not sure my method for this is correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, date  
FROM `tblinvoices`  
INNER JOIN (SELECT userid,tblinvoiceitems.relid  
FROM  `tblinvoiceitems`  
INNER JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues`  
ON tblinvoiceitems.relid=tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid  
WHERE  `fieldid` =5  
AND  `value`   
REGEXP  '[A-Za-z]') tbl  
ON tblinvoices.userid=tbl.userid  
WHERE `taxrate` = 0  
AND `date`  
BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'
```

simplified, but still not correct results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.date  
FROM `tblinvoices` i
INNER JOIN `tblinvoiceitems`  it ON it.userid=i.userid
INNER JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues`  cf ON it.relid=cf.relid  
WHERE  cf.`fieldid` =5  
AND  cf.`value` REGEXP  '[A-Za-z]'
AND i.`taxrate` = 0  
AND i.`date`  BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'  
GROUP BY i.id
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just simplifying your query. Try this

```
SELECT i.id, i.date  
FROM `tblinvoices` i
INNER JOIN `tblinvoiceitems`  it ON it.userid=i.userid
INNER JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues`  cf ON it.relid=cf.relid  
WHERE  cf.`fieldid` =5  
AND i.`taxrate` = 0  
AND i.`date`  BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'  
GROUP BY i.id
```

Hope this will work

Comment: It does need the DISTINCT otherwise it is returning a lot of duplicate results, and it's missing the value regexp, I added this above now and it is simplified but returns the same results which aren't correct :/

Comment: it turns out I was actually checking a wrong field, thanks for the help!